# ember - observing global and injected properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember-auth to manage sessions in my ember application. Ember-auth provides an auth object that is automatically injected in every route and controller.

I have a user registration route in my application. I want to transition the user away from this route if they login while in this route. For that purpose, I came up with this code:

```
App.RegisterRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    // redirect the user if he is already logged in
    redirect: function() {
        if (this.auth.get('signedIn')) {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    },


    //check if user logged in and redirect him if he did
    loginStatusChanged: (function() {
        if (this.auth.get('signedIn')) {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    }).observes('auth.signedIn'),

    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('user', App.User.create());
    },
});
```

The code works, however, the observer fires in every route, not just when the user is in the   register route.

My solution, right now, is to get the current route, check if it's equal to 'register' and only then make the transition. This does not seem ideal. Is there an "ember way" of doing this?